# Is it better to use very complicated words in CPE essay?

Tags: exam-questions

In the Cambridge CPE Exam, is it better to use very complicated and less common words in my essay in the writing part? Will points be deducted?

Comment: It depends. If you use uncommon words where more common words would be more appropriate, then your writing style could be viewed as obscure or less clear.

Comment: [20 Advanced (C2) English Verbs | Vocabulary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqiLoPKSAJ4)

Comment: This question is about test-taking, not learning English. It's also a matter of opinion, not fact, so I have closed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an examiner for Cambridge exams, I can ensure you that you don't need to worry using complicated words, your points won't be deducted. In fact, there is a part called language when we're giving the marks. The language part depends on how you use the vocabularies, hence if you use difficult words, your score may be even higher.

Comment: At proficiency level you are expected to produce level C2 vocabulary. It doesn't necessarily mean they are complicated to a native speaker but the words will certainly be uncommon for most learners of English.